# How do I take the event that triggered an Azure Devops pipeline into account in that pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a multi-stage YAML pipeline using a template. I would like to do different things depending on which git branch was pushed to. If it's master, I'd like to do one thing, and if it's dev, I'd like to do something else.  I imagining something like

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
   condition:  eq(trigger, "master") 
   inputs:
         rootFolderOrFile: 'C:\DevOps\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Content\D_C\a\1\s\api\obj\${{ parameters.configuration }}\Package\PackageTmp' 
         includeRootFolder: false 
         archiveType: 'zip' 
         archiveFile: 'C:\DevOps\artifacts\api-${{ parameters.configuration }}.zip' 
         replaceExistingArchive: true 
         verbose: true
                      
- task: CopyFiles@2
   condition:  eq(trigger, "dev") 
   inputs:  
         SourceFolder: 'C:\DevOps\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Content\D_C\a\1\s\api\obj\${{ parameters.configuration }}\Package\PackageTmp'
         Contents: '**\*.*'
         OverWrite: true
         TargetFolder: 'C:\QA\Web Sites\API${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

Obviously this isn't going to work, because "trigger" is not defined.  But if I wanted to act based on the git branch pushed to, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Where I had

```
condition:  eq(trigger, "master")
```

I just need to make it

```
condition eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'master')
```

***Side note:*** In such comparisons, it turns out that double quotes don't work; I'm sure there's a reason, though I've never seen this mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: The failure of double quotes is indeed a bit surprising at first, since in YAML both single and double quotes are allowed. (Double quoted strings undergo backslash interpretation but `"master"` and `'master'` both denote a string.) But these aren't really *YAML* strings at all as they're arguments to the `eq(...)`, which is the YAML string. So the quotes are preserved and passed to whatever is interpreting them. This *should* be documented somewhere (I have no idea whether it actually *is* documented anywhere, though).